# How does JavaScript/jQuery invoke callback functions on multiple ajax responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I know that the a in ajax means asynchronous, and as such there is no guarantee which order my responses will come back in, in fact its reasonable to expect the largest payload to return last.

My question however is regarding the callbacks. Sometimes when I notice my responses come back in a different order to which they were sent, the 'wrong' callback is invoked.

Take the function below.
There are some values `(rangesize, dropskus, limit)` (commented below) which are unique to each call, and defined in the success callback for each. When I run the script and send 5 calls, if they do come back in a different order to which they were sent. Let's say the largest response was the 2nd call to be made, that response comes back last and also invokes the last callback function.

So my question:

**Does or should JavaScript / jQuery know which callback function to invoke when returning multiple responses?**

Or would it be better for me to use synchronous calls?

Other notes:
When debugging in chrome, I noticed that the console logs of the responses say `filename.js:linenumber`. Whereas previously when I've used multiple ajax calls the console logs say `VM12*:linenumber`. I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue I'm facing, but I did notice that when this was the case the correct callbacks were always invoked.

```
function generateReview(){

  var subcategories = subcatstring.split(",");

  $("#rangereviewtable").html("");
  $("#rangereviewtable").append(thead);

  var i = 0;
  var iterations = subcategories.length;
  $.each(subcategories, function(key, value) {

        var postdata = {group: group,
                        class: rrclass,
                        category: category,
                        subcategory: value,
                        period: period,
                        periodval: periodval,
                        stores: storesarray};
        console.log(postdata);

        $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxrangereview.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postdata,
                success: function (response) {

                  //VALUES UNIQUE TO EACH CALL
                  var rangesize = parseInt($("#rangesize" + i).text());
                  console.log("range size: " + rangesize);
                  var dropskus = parseInt($("#dropskus" + i).text());
                  console.log("dropskus: " + dropskus);
                  var limit = rangesize - dropskus;
                  console.log("limit: " + limit);

                  console.log(response);

                  var rrtable = "";

                        $.each(response, function(i, item) {

                            rrtable += "<tr>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewtext'>" + item.category + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewtext'>" + item.subcategory + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewtext'>" + item.brand + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewtext'>" + item.sku + " - " + item.product + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.py3.toLocaleString("en") + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.py2.toLocaleString("en") + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.py1.toLocaleString("en") + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.average.toLocaleString("en") + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.sales.toLocaleString("en") + "</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td class='rangereviewnumber'>" + item.share + "%</td>";
                              rrtable += "<td>&#x2714</td>";

                              if(limit >= item.idnum){

                                  rrtable += "<td>&#x2714</td>";
                                  rrtable += "<td class='checkboxcell' onClick=\"toggleCheckMark(this, '" + item.brand + "')\">&#x2714</td>";

                              } else {

                                  rrtable += "<td></td>";
                                  rrtable += "<td class='checkboxcell' onClick=\"toggleCheckMark(this, '" + item.brand + "')\"></td>";

                              }

                            rrtable += "</tr>";
                        });
                    // increment iterations
                    i += 1;

                    $("#rangereviewtable").append(rrtable);

                    if(i == iterations){

                      var headimage = "<img src='http://url.com/images/oimage.png' width='63.5px' height='76px'>";
                      var table = $("#rangereviewtable").DataTable({
                                                                    buttons: [{extend: 'excelHtml5', title: 'Range Review', text: 'Export to Excel'},
                                                                              {extend: 'print', title: 'Range Review', message: headimage}],
                                                                  });
                      //insert export to excel button into #rrbuttons div above actual table.
                      table.buttons().container().appendTo( $('#rrbuttons') );

                      $("#rangereviewpanel").show();
                      $("#generatebutton").hide();
                      $("#loadbutton").hide();
                      $("#saveasbutton").show();
                      generateReviewSummary(summaryarray);

                    } else {

                      //do nothing not all iterations complete

                    }

                    },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    i+= 1;
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                  }
            });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case I think it will work fine (your code does something like):

```
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(j);
        j++
    }, 1000)
}
```

This code will outputs numbers 0..9;
But let see another example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000)
}
```

It outputs 9..9
So it is not safe approach to call async functions inside synchronous loop. You can use async.each (https://github.com/caolan/async#each) or promises to handle it.

Comment: I think maybe promises might be something for me to look at. but there again, I don't append to my table until all calls are complete and returned anyway, so I suppose there is no harm in using `async: false` here. I just don't want that synx xhr deprecated error! Thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: @AdamCopley Ok, i got it. You want to wait until all requests done? You can use async.each (link from answer). It final callback will be call when every request done. And it much better than `async: false` because all request are still be parallel

Comment: The way I have it is that, I want the callback function to do some of its own stuff to the response (do calculations with rangesize, dropskus and limit), before appending it to the `rrtable` variable. Then once all calls are complete, append the rrtable string to the html table.

Comment: @AdamCopley Callback will do their stuff. You should keep in mind that actual values of variables inside callback will be substituted when callback will be fired but not when it declared.

Comment: That's where I'm lacking, it's the variables within the callback which are replaced when they're invoked by other responses beforehand. I now understand what is happening.  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript / jQuery knows exactly what callback to invoke, and is doing so correctly.

You need to learn more about JavaScript closures and scope.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'wrong' and 'right' callback with respect to your logic.  If you want the special-logic to kick-in when you receive the response to the last *request*, then perhaps you could try replacing your use of `i` with references to `key` instead (or if I'm reading your logic correctly, you might want to use `key + 1`)

Comment: Perhaps scope is the problem. I will use key in place of `i` because they do hold the same value throughout, but that is small.  

Is it not correct that the anonymous function which is defined in `success:` and the values of it's variables therein are stored until the specific response is received?

Comment: The locally declared variable `postdata` along with the `key` and `value` function arguments are part of the closure for the callback.  Variables such as `i` are part of the scope chain and are subject to change.

MDN has a nice article on closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: `i` won't hold the same value as you can't guarantee in what order the async calls are executed/returned from the web server.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand, looks like I need to be using synchronous calls in this case.   Thanks for your info, and links much appreciated.

Comment: @AdamCopley Reading your other comments, the code in your question is probably using `i` correctly (even if that's pure luck.)  You may want to consider an alternative solution to blindly calling `$("#rangereviewtable").append(rrtable)` on each response - which I guess is causing your rows to appear in unwanted order?

Comment: I have just spotted that and adjusted it so that append is called only once, after iterations are complete.  though it's not actually the order of the rows I'm concerned about. The value of `limit` defines whether a certain row(s) has a check mark in it or not, when compared against a value in the return json. hence the need for `i` to be the correct value when callback is invoked. but Thanks!